# Converting array into grayscale in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, plot, grayscale

I am trying to plot a set of data in grayscale. However, the image i get seems to be always blue.

I have a set of data, `albedo` that ranges from `[0, 0.068]`, which is a `1X1 double`.

My code is:

```
 for all px,py
    albedoMax = 0.0679; albedoMin = 0;
    out_im(px,py) = 1/(albedoMax-albedoMin)*(albedo - albedoMin);
    imshow(out_im);
    drawnow;
 end
```

Basically `px,py` are the image coordinates that i have to iterate over, and the formula is trying to map the input range of `[0, 0.068]` to `[0 1]`. However, by running this code, i notice that the output is always blueish. I was wondering what went wrong.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is this your actual Matlab code, or pseudocode?

Comment: except for the "for" and "end" part, all the others are actual

Answer (score 0):

Can't you make use of the rgb2gray function?

Comment: the dimensions for my albedo doesn't match an rgb array. Should i concatenate it to make it look like one?

Comment: To get a grayscale value you need to multiply a pixel's red, green, and blue values by certain constants. Then add them together to get a grayscale value.

Answer (score 0):

What you are making is one layer of the RGB image.
If you are creating a homogeneous blue image with constant color then the normalization is wrong. But if it is just the matter of being blue instead of being gray then just convert it using :

```
ImGray = rgb2gray(Im);
```

Do not forget to distribute the pixels like a grid/mesh, to fill all the image not just a part of it.